# Apache : Making one virtual host subdomain/subdirectory of another virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, virtualhost, subdomain, django

My setup is a bit awkward. I've got http://sub.main.com mapped to my server's IP but not the http://main.com. I am running two sites on my server(using different web frameworks). For each of those sites I've got virtual hosts configured in default site, which looks something like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ServerName "sub.main.com"
    DocumentRoot "/var/www"
    ....
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName appsphere.djangoserver
    Alias /media /srv/www/appsphere/media/
    ......
    ......
    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/appsphere/apache/django.wsgi

</VirtualHost>
```

Now how can I make my second virtual host a subdirectory/subdomain of first virtual host. I want to access the second site using `http://sub.main.com/appsphere`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your first VirtualHost declaration to the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ServerName "sub.main.com"
    DocumentRoot "/var/www"

    Alias /appsphere/media /srv/www/appsphere/media
    WSGIScriptAlias /appsphere /srv/www/appsphere/apache/django.wsgi

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I needed to change the /media settings in second virtual host to /appsphere/media, but rest was a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as adding a few lines to your first VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ServerName "sub.main.com"
    DocumentRoot "/var/www"

    Alias /appsphere/media /srv/www/appsphere/media/
    ......
    ......
    WSGIScriptAlias /appsphere /srv/www/appsphere/apache/django.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't know what you have in the "......." section that may need updating to reflect the path change as well.